# Concatenate dataframe name with variable value Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a variable **mmmyy=Jul18** and want to create a dataframe in python using this variable named as **df_Jul18**. mmmyy is a dynamic variable for next month the df name will be **df_Aug18**.

Could anyone please help me achieving this. I tried my best but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Don't create dynamically named variables

It is poor practice: makes your code intractable, clutters the namespace, removes the connection between related variables.

#### Use a dictionary instead

Usefully, Python provides an efficient method to provide labels for variables via hashable keys. The use of `dict` will make your life easier and make your code more readable. For example:

```
dfs = {}

mmmyy = 'Jul18'
dfs[mmmyy] = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

print(dfs)

{'Jul18': Empty DataFrame
          Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
          Index: []}
```

Then access your dataframe via `dfs['Jul18']`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and correcting me with the right approach. I will definitely use the dictionary in such scenarios. It helped me a lot. Cheers, keep rolling good stuff; highly appreciated!